# Insert into table with user input

Tags: php, html, mysql

This may have an easy solution but i'm stumped here. As you can see below, I want an employee to be able to request as much as 6 different items in one form. The problem for me is, how to store 6 possible values for (Item Number, Ited Description, Qty Requested and Request Purpose) in their respective columns? I could use array but that will just make it more complicated.

This is my table description:

```
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field              | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Request_Number     | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Request_Date       | date         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Department         | varchar(30)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Email              | varchar(80)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Item_Number        | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Item_Description   | varchar(250) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Quantity_Requested | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Request_Purpose    | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Sub_Dept_Head      | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Dept_Head          | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Admin_Dept         | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Approved_By        | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

This is the form:

```
    <form class="Requisition_form" id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
      <table width="100%" border="2" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
        <tr>
          <th colspan="7">Personal Detail:</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="155"><strong>Request Date:</strong></td>
          <td width="199"><label>
            <input size="30" type="date" name="date" id="date" placeholder="yyyy/mm/dd"/>
          </label></td>
          <td width="133"><strong>Department</strong></td>
          <td width="182"><label>
            <input size="30" type="text" name="department" id="department" />
          </label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><strong>Requested By:</strong></td>
          <td><label>
            <input size="30" type="text" name="requested_by" id="requested_by" />
          </label></td>
          <td><strong>E-Mail:</strong></td>
          <td><label>
            <input size="30" type="email" name="email" id="email" />
          </label></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <table width="100%" border="2" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="4">Requisition Detail:</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="25%" align="center"><strong>Item Number</strong></td>
      <td width="25%" align="center"><strong>Item Description</strong></td>
      <td width="25%" align="center"><strong>Quantity Requested</strong></td>
      <td width="25%" align="center"><strong>Request Purpose</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center"><label>
        <input size="30" type="text" name="item_number" id="item_number" />
      </label></td>
      <td align="center"><label>
        <input size="30" type="text" name="item_description" id="item_description" />
      </label></td>
      <td align="center"><label>
        <input size="30" type="text" name="qty_requested" id="qty_requested" />
      </label></td>
      <td align="center"><label>
        <input size="30" type="text" name="request_purpose" id="request_purpose" />
        </label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center"><input size="30" type="text" name="item_number2" id="item_number2" /></td>
      <td align="center"><input size="30" type="text" name="item_description2" id="item_description2" /></td>
      <td align="center"><input size="30" type="text" name="qty_requested2" id="qty_requested2" /></td>
      <td align="center"><input size="30" type="text" name="request_purpose2" id="request_purpose2" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center"><input size="30" type="text" name="item_number3" id="item_number3" /></td>
      <td align="center"><input size="30" type="text" name="item_description3" id="item_description3" /></td>
      <td align="center"><input size="30" type="text" name="qty_requested3" id="qty_requested3" /></td>
      <td align="center"><input size="30" type="text" name="request_purpose3" id="request_purpose3" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center"><input size="30" type="text" name="item_number4" id="item_number4" /></td>
      <td align="center"><input size="30" type="text" name="item_description4" id="item_description4" /></td>
      <td align="center"><input size="30" type="text" name="qty_requested4" id="qty_requested4" /></td>
      <td align="center"><input size="30" type="text" name="request_purpose4" id="request_purpose4" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center"><input size="30" type="text" name="item_number5" id="item_number5" /></td>
      <td align="center"><input size="30" type="text" name="item_description5" id="item_description5" /></td>
      <td align="center"><input size="30" type="text" name="qty_requested5" id="qty_requested5" /></td>
      <td align="center"><input size="30" type="text" name="request_purpose5" id="request_purpose5" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center"><input size="30" type="text" name="item_number6" id="item_number6" /></td>
      <td align="center"><input size="30" type="text" name="item_description6" id="item_description6" /></td>
      <td align="center"><input size="30" type="text" name="qty_requested6" id="qty_requested6" /></td>
      <td align="center"><input size="30" type="text" name="request_purpose6" id="request_purpose6" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

      <table width="100%" border="2" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
        <tr>
          <th colspan="4">Recommendations:</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="center"><strong>Sub-Department Head</strong></td>
          <td align="center"><strong>Department Head</strong></td>
          <td align="center"><strong>Administration</strong></td>
          <td align="center"><strong>Approved by</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="center"><input size="30" type="text" name="sub_dept_head" id="sub_dept_head" /></td>
          <td align="center"><input size="30" type="text" name="dept_head" id="dept_head" /></td>
          <td align="center"><input size="30" type="text" name="admin_dept" id="admin_dept" /></td>
          <td align="center"><input size="30" type="text" name="approved_by" id="approved_by" /></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: "I could use array but that will just make it more complicated." How would it? I think this is the perfect scenario to use one

Comment: +1 @DavidJones. If there ever was a reason to use an array, this is a perfect example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using an array to capture the input values. You need to change each row with the inputs to this:

```
 <tr>
      <td align="center"><label>
        <input size="30" type="text" name="item_number[]" id="item_number" />
      </label></td>
      <td align="center"><label>
        <input size="30" type="text" name="item_description[]" id="item_description" />
      </label></td>
      <td align="center"><label>
        <input size="30" type="text" name="qty_requested[]" id="qty_requested" />
      </label></td>
      <td align="center"><label>
        <input size="30" type="text" name="request_purpose[]" id="request_purpose" />
        </label></td>
    </tr>
```

Now in your PHP you can simply loop through and grab each item per row.

```
$c = count($_POST['item_number']);
for ($i = 0; $i < $c; $i++) {
    $item_number = $_POST['item_number'][$i];
    $item_description= $_POST['item_description'][$i];
    $qty_requested= $_POST['qty_requested'][$i];
    $request_purpose= $_POST['request_purpose'][$i];

    // Enter to database or whatever
}
```

But this will still not work as your database is not set up correctly. You need to have a separate table for the items then set up a one to many relationship with the requests.

If you cant change your database structure for whatever reason then you will need to serialize each array then enter the serialized string into the database. For example:

```
$item_number = serialize($_POST['item_number']);
$item_description= serialize($_POST['item_description']);
$qty_requested= serialize($_POST['qty_requested']);
$request_purpose= serialize($_POST['request_purpose']);
```

Hope that helps :)